# Why Amazon SQS messages drop Consumer get no message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, mq

I am sending message on sqs queue and strangely message are getting dropped or deleted before consumer reads it.

I have logged activity, I can see message successfully going on queue but consumer not getting it.

What can be the reason?

This [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94258) is related , but op resolved it in private so sadly no solution

Comment: How do you know that the messages are being dropped? What are the counts in the Management Console (include a screenshot)? You'll need to provide more information to obtain a useful answer.

Comment: are you doing this to get messages from amazon seller central?@Shagayag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not happen. Something in your system is deleting the messages.

It could be that you are viewing them in the console, which could trigger the [Visibility Timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html). During that timeout, the messages will be invisible ("In Flight"), waiting for the requesting process to delete them once processed.

The flow is:

- `SendMessage` pushes message to the queue ("Messages Available")
- `ReceiveMessage` retrieves message from the queue ("Messages In Flight")
- Application processes message (message remains invisible)
- If the message visibility timeout is exceeded, the message re-appears on the queue
- `DeleteMessage` deletes the message from the queue